# Need help creating Digest authentication for Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, digest-authentication

I have this code so far:

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... theParams) 
        {
            String myUrl = theParams[0];
            String myEmail = theParams[1];
            String myPassword = theParams[2];

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(myUrl);
            post.addHeader("Authorization","Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString((myEmail+":"+myPassword).getBytes(), 0 ));
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

            String response = null;

            try 
            {
                    response = client.execute(post, responseHandler);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        response += s;
                    }
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            return response;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            }

}
```

This code does not compile because I am running into confusion at the point of:

```
                response = client.execute(post, responseHandler);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
```

I got that code from tinkering with various examples, and not sure what Object the client is supposed to be, and whether the first line will just get me the server response, or I have to go the route of getting the InputStream and reading the server response in?

Please help me understand how to do this correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: 1. client is HttpClient 2. client.execute(...) returns HttpResponse, not a String 3. InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent() (response mean HttpResponse);

Comment: @appserv I am confused what object is client :) How do I get the client object? :)

Comment: HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to switch to [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). According to [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) its API is simpler than `HttpClient`'s and it's better supported on Android. If you do choose to go with `HttpURLConnection`, authenticating is pretty simple:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password".toCharArray());
    }
});
```

After that, continue using `HttpURLConnection` as usual. A simple example:

```
final URL url = new URL("http://example.com/");
final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
final InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
final byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];
int readCount;
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while ((readCount = is.read(buffer)) > -1) {
    builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, readCount));
}
final String response = builder.toString();
```

Comment: what is the benefit of switching to HttpUrlConnection? Also, would your suggested approach still be in line of the Android Digest Authentication method?  Thanks!

Comment: @GeekedOut the benefits of switching to `HttpURLConnection` are outlined in the linked article. As for digest auth support, yes, the `Authenticator` method supports HTTP Basic, HTTP Digest, NTLM and SPNEGO authentication, as outlined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html). It picks the appropriate auth method depending on the server's response.

Comment: but the link you provided discusses other things. I am confused where to place and how to invoke the Authenticator snippet. Should it be inside the inner class which extends AsyncTask? Or outside? And is it called implicitly or explicitly? Thanks!

Comment: The link I provided discusses `HttpURLConnection` vs. Apache's `HttpClient` and how the former is better on Android. As for the code, I don't know what you mean by "implicitly or explicitly". For simplicity's sake, you could simply combine the two bits of code in my answer in one big `doInBackground` method in your `AsyncTask`. However, since you asked the "where does this bit of code go" question, I'd say you should study Java more, as this is not an Android-specific issue.

Comment: @Felix - you mentioned the linked article works for NTLM and SPNEGO among the others. Did you get it working for those in particular? I was able to get Basic working. But for NTLM/SPNEGO, the getPasswordAuthentication() is never invoked. Did you have to carry out any extra steps?

Comment: @Felix You also mentioned Digest, from the documentation I've read the Android version of the Authenticator only supports Basic and nothing more. Did you ever get Digest to work?

Comment: @Etienne do you have a link to that info? I was looking and couldn't find.

Comment: @Michel check out this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.htmlunder the section HTTP Authentication. It only lists Basic Authentication.

Comment: @Etienne `Error 404 File not found` the correct link is [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) without the "under". Thanks =)

Comment: Thanks Micheal. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 5):

I have managed to use Digest authentication using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). In this code sample I also use Dagger and Robospice-retrofit. What I did was creating an [OkHttp Authenticator](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#handling-authentication) and assign it to my custom OkHttp client.

The authenticator class implements an *authenticate* method that will be called whenever the server encounters a 401 error and expects an *Authorization* header back (if it expects *Proxy-Authorization* you should implement the *authenticateProxy* method.

What it basically does is wrapping calls to the HttpClient DigestScheme and make it usable for OkHttp. Currently it does not increase the nc counter. This could cause problems with your server as it could be interpreted as a replay attack.

```
public class DigestAuthenticator implements com.squareup.okhttp.Authenticator {
    @Inject DigestScheme mDigestScheme;
    @Inject org.apache.http.auth.Credentials mCredentials;

    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
        String authHeader = buildAuthorizationHeader(response);
        if (authHeader == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return response.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", authHeader).build();
    }

    @Override
    public Request authenticateProxy(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }

    private String buildAuthorizationHeader(Response response) throws IOException {
        processChallenge("WWW-Authenticate", response.header("WWW-Authenticate"));
        return generateDigestHeader(response);
    }

    private void processChallenge(String headerName, String headerValue) {
        try {
            mDigestScheme.processChallenge(new BasicHeader(headerName, headerValue));
        } catch (MalformedChallengeException e) {
            Timber.e(e, "Error processing header " + headerName + " for DIGEST authentication.");
        }
    }

    private String generateDigestHeader(Response response) throws IOException {
        org.apache.http.HttpRequest request = new BasicHttpRequest(
                response.request().method(),
                response.request().uri().toString()
        );

        try {
            return mDigestScheme.authenticate(mCredentials, request).getValue();
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            Timber.e(e, "Error generating DIGEST auth header.");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The authenticator will then be used in an OkHttpClient built with a provider:

```
public class CustomClientProvider implements Client.Provider {
    @Inject DigestAuthenticator mDigestAuthenticator;

    @Override
    public Client get() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setAuthenticator(mDigestAuthenticator);
        return new OkClient(client);
    }
}
```

Finally the client is set to the RetrofitRobospice server in the function *createRestAdapterBuilder*:

```
public class ApiRetrofitSpiceService extends RetrofitJackson2SpiceService {
    @Inject Client.Provider mClientProvider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        App.get(this).inject(this);
        super.onCreate();
        addRetrofitInterface(NotificationRestInterface.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getServerUrl() {
        return Constants.Url.BASE;
    }

    @Override
    protected RestAdapter.Builder createRestAdapterBuilder() {
        return super.createRestAdapterBuilder()
                .setClient(mClientProvider.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange, I always get 400 bad request using your technique - I'm not using RetrofitRobospice though - do you think it's relevant? I don't see how it could be, but I don't have musch experience with robospice

Comment: Are you still using Retrofit anyway? Could you post the whole request ans response?

Comment: Yes, I use Retrofit. The request that gets generated in authenticate's return statement has only 2 headers,here they are (and response too):http://pastebin.com/QV8hm8Kq

Comment: The request is GET or POST. I can't figure out what is wrong with your request. You could take a look at RFC specificacion for the HTTP Digest authentication the request is properly generated. You could also check the server is properly configured.

If you find the problem, do tell us and I will update my answer.

Comment: it's GET. Server seems to be OK, because it responds correctly to requests made with CURL.

Answer (score 3):

The version of Apache's `HttpClient` shipped with Android is [based on an old, pre-BETA version of `HttpClient`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html). Google has [long recommended against using it](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) and [removed it in Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html). Google's replacement `HttpURLConnection` [does not support HTTP digest authentication](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), only basic.

This leaves you with a few options, including:

- Migrate to `HttpURLConnection` (as Google recommends) and use a library, [bare-bones-digest](https://github.com/al-broco/bare-bones-digest), for digest authentication. Example below.
- Use the [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) library instead of `HttpURLConnection` or `HttpClient`. OkHttp does not support digest out of the box, but there's a library [okhttp-digest](https://github.com/rburgst/okhttp-digest) that implements a digest authenticator. Example below.
- Continue using the (deprecated) `HttpClient` by explicitly adding the `'org.apache.http.legacy'` library to your build, as mentioned in the [changelist for Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html).
- There is an Apache project for porting newer versions of `HttpClient` to Android, but the project has been discontinued. Read more on [Apache's page on HttpClient for Android](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android-port.html).
- Implement HTTP digest yourself.

Here is a verbose example of how to authenticate a request using [bare-bones-digest](https://github.com/al-broco/bare-bones-digest) and `HttpURLConnection` (copied from the project's github page):

```
// Step 1. Create the connection
URL url = new URL("http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Step 2. Make the request and check to see if the response contains
// an authorization challenge
if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
    // Step 3. Create a authentication object from the challenge...
    DigestAuthentication auth = DigestAuthentication.fromResponse(connection);
    // ...with correct credentials
    auth.username("user").password("passwd");

    // Step 4 (Optional). Check if the challenge was a digest
    // challenge of a supported type
    if (!auth.canRespond()) {
        // No digest challenge or a challenge of an unsupported
        // type - do something else or fail
        return;
    }

    // Step 5. Create a new connection, identical to the original
    // one..
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    // ...and set the Authorization header on the request, with the
    // challenge response
    connection.setRequestProperty(
        DigestChallengeResponse.HTTP_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION,
        auth.getAuthorizationForRequest("GET", connection.getURL().getPath()));
}
```

Here is an example using [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) and [okhttp-digest](https://github.com/rburgst/okhttp-digest) (copied from the okhttp-digest page):

```
client = new OkHttpClient();
final DigestAuthenticator authenticator = new DigestAuthenticator(new Credentials("username", "pass"));

final Map<String, CachingAuthenticator> authCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
client.interceptors().add(new AuthenticationCacheInterceptor(authCache));
client.setAuthenticator(new CachingAuthenticatorDecorator(authenticator, authCache));

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url(url);
  .get()
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```