# How to use Digest authentication in Android Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, digest-authentication

I am creating an Android application that request to a server authenticated by digest authentication method. I am using Retrofit to do the requests. Can someone explain me how to do this?

Comment: You need to specify a `Client` for your rest adapter builder that handles digest authentication.

Comment: Can be more specific, please? I have already add a custom client, but I don't know how to add digest authentication to that client.

Comment: Depends on the type of `Client`. Is it `Apache HttpClient` or `OkHttpClient` or...?

Comment: I'm using OkHttpClient

Comment: Apparently you need to implement `okhttp.Authenticator` akin to this particular setup https://gist.github.com/fqueiruga/f3f60f7dda50b8c7adc6  and most importantly https://gist.github.com/fqueiruga/f3f60f7dda50b8c7adc6#file-digestauthenticator-java this is the only thing I've found about this, but I haven't worked with Digest auth so I can't provide an extensive answer on what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what Jake Wharton said at [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/205), you need to implement the `Authenticator` class. Apparently what you need has been figured out by Felix Queiruga at [this particular answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24672339/2413303)

Comment: I cannot figure out how I can pass username and password to the custom client in that answer.

Comment: It seems to be injected externally using that `credentials` object which probably received it from a module that was instantiated with a username / password parameter. Also I'm trying to look up a way to integrate the Apache HttpClient digest methods - for example, when I needed Client Authentication, I took the SslContextBuilder from the Apache HttpCore because it worked perfectly fine on its own. There must be a way to migrate the Apache Http digest auth....

Comment: This would be what needs to be decrypted for OkHttp http://stackoverflow.com/a/27069911/2413303